# merging list of tuples and list and create dictionary

Tags: python

I have a list with a list of tuples and a list with 2 items. I Need to merge and create a new dictionary.

Here is an example:
Input:

```
list1 = [('col1',20,30),('col2',40,50)]
list2 = ['name','age']
```

Desired result:

```
 output = {'col1':'name','col2':'age'}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
output = {el1[0]: el2 for el1, el2 in zip(list1, list2)}
```

Or for old versions of Python:

```
output = dict((el1[0], el2) for el1, el2 in zip(list1, list2))
```

Comment: @user1050619 Runs okay on Python 2.7. The code you posted has a typo. Definition for `list1` has an extra closing parenthesis.